# Internet Wifi Devices Application

Tags: architecture

If some one is using plug in internet connector and try to configure something. Devices give instructions like IP Address which is some local IP like 192.16X.X.X and give default username and password.

We login using that in browser and can see the HTML pages. My question is how those applications are Served, what they are called and can we use simple HTML, CSS, JS or angular node for making such a application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started to work on this app. We call in In Box solution. We just run it as any application. Just bind it to some internal IP Address of the device.